# How to change pass some integer value in steps of 50 to a C++ code

Tags: c++, c

I have a code which takes some integer values ex : 35005. I want to compile the code once and then pass the start integer value and end integer value for which I want the code to run. These are in increments of 50. Like 35005, 35055, 36005 and so on.

I want to write something like ./a.out 35005  50   36005 and submit jobs.

Till now, I am using something like :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[] )
 {
 int input = atoi(argv[1]);
int nConfig(1);
int initConfig (input);
```

This takes only one value and not what I want as stated above. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You should test `argc` and you could do a loop `(for int argix=1; argix<argc; argix++)`

Comment: 35055 + 50 =35105 not `36005`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch not sure what you're trying to do with that loop but argc is the number of arguments and his input is (start, step, end) not three values

Comment: Source code is uncountable and does not allow an indefinite article, btw.

Comment: This is not a good question. In fact, it's barely a question. This is not a forum where people will do your programming for you. When you have given it a try, searched around and maybe read a book/tutorial on basic C-programming, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is a good place to find out how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse 3 arguments, not just one.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[] )
{
   int start = atoi(argv[1]);  // 35005
   int interval = atoi(argv[2]); // 50
   int end = atoi(argv[3]); // 36005
```

Ofcourse, you should also check that `argc` to make sure you have enough arguments

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, your program takes 3 arguments : start value, increment and end value.
So:

```
if( argc >= 4 ) {
    int start_value = atoi( argv[1] );
    int incr_value = atoi( argv[2] );
    int end_value = atoi( argv[3] );
    // .. do what you want ...
}
```